# Can I Use Different Bank Accounts to fulfill UK Visit Visa's Financial Requirement?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, family

I have money in two different accounts (different banks) and can I use both of them to fulfil UK visit visa's financial requirement?

And another question related to this => how long the money has to be in my account?

Comment: Not a problem... all other things being equal.

Comment: Having two accounts could cause them to give greater scrutiny to your finances, but they already give finances a fairly thorough look, so as @GayotFow says, you shouldn't be too concerned about having two accounts. The "how long" question, though, raises the question of potential "funds parking," which they do not like at all.  See [tag:proof-provenance-of-funds].

Answer (score 2):

What they want to see is a *steady income* which exceeds your *reasonable expenses* so that you can *reasonably afford* your visit. This is much more important than the total amount and how long you had the money.

- Where does the money come from? If it looks as if you had to borrow it, people will ask how you plan to repay that investment. If it was a gift, you have to explain that it was a gift and not a loan. Best if it is your income.
- Are your earnings steady and predictable? That also helps to establish stable ties to your home and your intention to return.
- How long did you have to save for the trip? Usually it is unreasonable to save several years for a brief vacation.

Comment: Hi @o.m. the person I'm applying for, I'm showing that, he's retired and currently his income source is some savings, property rents and land lease. In that case is it necessary to show property's ownership papers or anything related to proof of property ownership or income justification etc?